# Javascript Scroll up and Down buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to make 2 buttons, one called "up" and one called "down".

Those should when I hold down my mouse on one of them, it should scroll up or down the whole page.

I tried with this code, but it didn't worked well.
            `<a href="#" id="up">Up</a>`
            `<a href="#" id="down">down</a>​`

```
        <script>

            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#down").hover(function () {
                    scroll_page("down");
                }, function() { $('.content').stop(); });

                $("#up").hover(function () {
                    scroll_page("up");
                }, function() { $('.content').stop(); });
            });

            function scroll_page(direction) {  
                var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop();
                if (direction == 'up') {
                    var scroll = scrolled + 100;
                }else{
                    var scroll = scrolled - 100;
                }

                $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: scroll }, "fast");
            }
    ​
        </script>
```

Does anyone have any ideas what to do?

Comment: try http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

Comment: @roine But I need it to constantly scroll on mouse is hold down?

Comment: @Nelson Im new to this site, so didn't knew about the accept thing.. But did it now :) And will do in future.

Comment: Use jquery `mousedown` and `mouseup` events. also declare `scroll` variable before `if` condition. `var scroll = 0;`

Comment: @Shahid I have done that now. But without any luck -.-'

Comment: jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/phdh5/2/

Comment: you may have to use this plugin for repeating trigger. [link](http://remysharp.com/2006/12/15/jquery-mousehold-event/)

Comment: rename `scroll` variable to `_scroll` or something else. i tried in an HTML file and it worked.